# Retrieve webBrowser.Document content from a worker in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, backgroundworker

I am having some issues with the following code, may you help me out with this please?

```
Uri siteUri = new Uri(url);
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { webBrowser.Source = siteUri; }));

dynamic result = Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{ return webBrowser.Document; });

var doc = result.documentElement.InnerHtml;

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

result or doc end up as "null". I am pretty sure I am missing something.

Please take note that I am new to using background workers.

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe the document is not loaded yet

Comment: Greetings, indeed the document was not loaded completely. Is there a good way to wait for the document to be loaded in WPF with the worker please? Thank you again.